# square root of a positive smooth monotone function

Tags: calculus

On R1 a function increases before its maximum point and decreases after reaches its maximum. If this function is smooth and have compact support, can we say its square root is smooth? Or what about the square root of a positive smooth monotone function, is it smooth?
 Here is a link:[Square root of compactly supported C-infinity function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186433/square-root-of-compactly-supported-c-infinity-function/1043178#1043178)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do mean positive and not non-negative in your second question, the answer is straightforward and does not even require monotonicity. If $\phi\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ is positive and $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, then $\phi$ is continuous and positive on $[a,b]$ and hence there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\phi(x)>\delta$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Since $y\mapsto\sqrt{y}$ is smooth on $[\delta,\infty)$ it follows from the chain rule that $\sqrt{\phi}$ is smooth on $[a,b]$.

The first question is trickier (as is the second if you meant non-negative) as the usual examples of smooth functions with non-smooth square roots do not have the monotonicity properties you describe.

Comment: Sorry actually I did mean it's non negative for my second question.